# how to make case insensitive query using variable?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I already have a user with a username **Kevin** in my database. I want prevent new users to pick **Kevin**, **kevin**, **KeViN**, etc. as their username when creating an account. How do I modify my query to check if such user exists ignoring case-sensitivity?

```
def validate_username(self, username):
    if db.users.find_one({"username":username}):
        raise ValidationError("username is already taken")
```

Comment: You could try `import re
regx = re.compile("^"+username.lower(), re.IGNORECASE)
db.users.find_one({"username": regx })`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it’s available on mongo directly. as an alternative, add another field to your user document and while saving username convert it into lowercase and save the hash-code in hash-code field.

So username : Kevin , hashcode : (hashcode of “kevin”)

Next time when a user enters 
Username : KeViN , hashcode : (hashcode of kevin)

Not if you put a validation or unique key constraint on handcode.. it should solve it.

Comment: Looking at other comments, yes regex should work. However, saving retrieving based on hash-code gives better performance...

Comment: thank you!! And do you really think it's better to store a special hash-code field? And why?

Comment: Thats easy, regex option is based on searching collection. If you check the compiled query, it’ll not hit any indexes but by having a field hashcode gives us flexibility to put an unique index on it and it’ll be way faster in retrieving results regardless of size of your collection

Answer (score 1):

```
db.users.find({ "username" : { "$regex" : username , "$options" : "i"}});
```

or

```
db.users.find({'username':{'$regex' : '^username$', '$options' : 'i'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

just put a "case-insensitive unique index" on the username field.

if someone enters an existing username, mongo will throw a duplicate key error which you can handle in your code and ask the user to enter another username.

you can create the index like this:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
    {
        username: "username_idx",
        unique: true,
        collation: {
            locale: "en",
            strength: 2
        }
    }
)
```